# How do they do this, ajax, json

Tags: ajax

I have been tasked with adding some functionality to a site [similar to this screen on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/roblawton/3847668339/in/photostream/).

Does anyone have any idea how they do the photostream on the right. The images are not in the javascript, json or there is no ajax request.

It would be really useful if anyone had an idea how they did this.

Comment: What do you mean? I see a _lot_ of traffic; one JSON, four thumbnails, even a tracking call to Yahoo Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an AJAX request performed as you scroll.

Open the console in your browser and look at the network tab. It will show a [link](http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&clientType=yui-3-flickrapi-module&api_key=8800e2eb03db7fb99992039f14061dcf&auth_hash=e65c85db55a2671d8d5968171150c516&auth_token=&secret=9978895fa92da630&photo_id=3396195710&num_prev=4&num_next=0&order_by=&extras=url_sq,url_q,url_t,url_s,url_m,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_o,video_size,owner_name,path_alias,icon_server,needs_interstitial,count_comments,count_faves,url_h,url_k&method=flickr.photos.getContext&jsoncallback=YUI.flickrAPITransactions.flapicb23&cachebust=1358811052893) similar to this:

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&clientType=yui-3-flickrapi-module&api_key=8800e2eb03db7fb99992039f14061dcf&auth_hash=e65c85db55a2671d8d5968171150c516&auth_token=&secret=9978895fa92da630&photo_id=3396195710&num_prev=4&num_next=0&order_by=&extras=url_sq%2Curl_q%2Curl_t%2Curl_s%2Curl_m%2Curl_z%2Curl_c%2Curl_l%2Curl_o%2Cvideo_size%2Cowner_name%2Cpath_alias%2Cicon_server%2Cneeds_interstitial%2Ccount_comments%2Ccount_faves%2Curl_h%2Curl_k&method=flickr.photos.getContext&jsoncallback=YUI.flickrAPITransactions.flapicb23&cachebust=1358811052893
```

This is the restful link which returns JSON data.  This JSON data contains the urls for the thumbnails of each of the photos, plus other information.

Answer (score 0):

1st There is ajax request when you scroll thumbnails on the right.
And I think that they make an ajax request with the last photo ID in the stream, the next pic in database or prev and the user  who uploaded pics and surely others params...
You want a script file that will give you picture thumb encoded in base64, url of the picture and next pictures id in database..

Example

```
$("#photostream > .scroll").click(function(){
    leftOrRight = $(this).attr("id"); // Assume that there is two buttons to get next or previous img with id #next and #prev
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlOfTheScriptFileThatWillProvideYouData.php, //aspx, jsp ...
        dataType: "json",
        data: "userId, photoId, leftOrRight",
    success: function(yourJson) {
        //... Do something with your data and append it in the slider etc..;

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
})
```

Look at URL

`http://www.flickr.com/photos/roblawton/3847619643/in/photostream/`

`http://www.flickr.com/photos/USER-ID/PHOTO-ID/in/photostream/`